# Automate Keycloak realm creation based on template

Tags: jakarta-ee, keycloak, keycloak-services

Let's say we have a multi-module applications which uses Keycloak authentication mechanism. We would like to automate as much as possible installation process of Keycloak with custom predefined realm settings. We would like to avoid using Keycloak API to configure realm settings while installation process.

Is there any known best practice to automatically create Keycloak schema based on predefined configuration values with some kind of template?

Answer (score 1):

You can import a Realm from file via CLI commands. This can be used to bootstrap a Keycloak installation.
That file can be exported beforehand and then modified so you will have a template.
For more information see https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#importing-a-realm-from-exported-json-file

Comment: This will work the first time, but if you try to import a second realm based on the same template, there will be id clashes, so you have to generate new uuids :-/

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible with the import via CLI commands - you just need to go one step further and make sure to delete every ID reference from the file you are importing. Keycloak will then generate new IDs where needed for the new realm.

Let's say you want each new realm to have 3 roles in it. This is how your `realm-template.json` would look like:

```
{
  "roles": {
    "realm": [
      {
        "name": "view-resource-1"
      },
      {
        "name": "view-resource-2"
      },
      {
        "name": "view-resource-3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can then use your template to create a realm called `realm-new` like this:

```
$ kcadm.sh create realms -s realm=realm-new -f realm-template.json
```